# use non-unique identifier to find sibling with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table of inputforms, one row roughly looks like this

```
    <tr>
     <td><input name ="surname"></td>
     <td><input name = "forename"></td>
     <td><button onclick="test(this)">SAVEME</button></td>
    </tr>
```

The test(param) function shall use jquery to iterate of the siblings of the button and select them by their name attributes. Is this possible? Or if not, what other ways of accomplishing this do I have?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where do you think it's failing?  Please share your code so people can help you with it rather than them writing it for you.  Also, you may want to consider rephrasing your question.  What do you mean by "select"?  Did you mean the siblings of the cell holding the button ... because the button quite literally has no siblings.

Comment: For this particular case I didn't try much because I don't really know how or IF jquery gives me methods to do so.

Comment: Yes, jQuery would let you do what I think you're asking in a variety of ways, but pretty much everyone reading this already knows how.  For you to learn, you need to try things yourself and ask the question about the things that you're trying that aren't working.

Comment: Yeah and that works perfectly by downvoting someone until he cant post any questions anymore. BestPractice.

Comment: It's not a best practice. It just indicates that people expect that you show some effort before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find closest tr and each input like this

```
function test(val){
  $(val).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(index, item){ 
    if($(item).attr('name') == 'surname'){
       console.log('Surname');
       // handle your logic with name surname here
    }
  })
}
```

```js
function test(val){
  
  $(val).closest('tr').find('input').each(function(index, item){ 

    if($(item).attr('name') == 'surname'){
    console.log('Surname');
 }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
     <td><input name ="surname"></td>
     <td><input name = "forename"></td>
     <td><button onclick="test(this)">SAVEME</button></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```